# Error in processing IFC file which is viewable in BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We receive an error while processing an IFC file in forge API. However, the file is viewable when we upload the file in BIM 360. Is there an option to set to process IFC file?

Error code:

{
"urn": "----",
"derivatives": [
{
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"name": "LMV Bubble",
"progress": "complete",
"messages": [
{
"type": "error",
"message": "Extractor - Adapter Process Timeout Error -444",
"code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
}
],
"outputType": "svf",
"status": "failed"
}
],
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"progress": "complete",
"type": "manifest",
"region": "US",
"version": "1.0",
"status": "failed"
}

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? It would be nice to include it with your question.

Comment: Also, BIM 360 uses the same Forge Model Derivative translation under-the-hood, so there should be no significant difference between the two approaches. Moreover, IFC files are a very common input in Forge, and there's no need for any custom configuration when translating them.

Comment: @PetrBroz Added an error code to the question. Thank you.